# Can't get background color working with html border

Tags: html, colors, background, border

I am using this code:

```html
<div style="width:850px;height:50px;padding:6px;border-width:4px;border-color:black;border-style:dotted hidden dotted hidden;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
<center><b>Net Worth:</B> <font color="green">€341,134.00</font> | <b>Distance Driven: </b><font color="lightgrey">10,610km</font> | <b>Employee Count:</b><font color="lightgrey"> 3</font></center></div>
```

But for some reason on my website as soon as I include

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
```

```html
<div style="width:850px;height:50px;padding:6px;border-width:4px;border-color:black;border-style:dotted hidden dotted hidden;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;background-color: rbga(0,0,0,.6);">
<center><b>Net Worth:</B> <font color="green">€341,134.00</font> | <b>Distance Driven: </b><font color="lightgrey">10,610km</font> | <b>Employee Count:</b><font color="lightgrey"> 3</font></center></div>
```

My border dis-appears and there is no background. But it's working everywhere else besides this site. Why? I even tried using just "background: rbga(0,0,0,.6);"

Answer (score 0):

You have written rbga instead of rgba . Is that how it is on your site?

Comment: Never noticed. It shouldn't matter though right? But yeah it's the same thing. The banner just disappears and no background color lol